# SQL Selecting an item where its date falls between a defined date range

Tags: sql, sapb1

I have this query that returns products that have have not been sold in 12 months:

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, ItemName
FROM OITM LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT ItemCode FROM RDR1 WHERE DocDate > DATEADD(yy,-1,GetDate()) GROUP BY ItemCode
) RDR1 ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OnHand > 0 AND RDR1.ItemCode IS NULL
```

I want to create different queries that pull items within different date ranges. I.e products not sold 1 to 3 months; 3 to 6 months; 6 to 9 months; 9 to 12 months; and over 12 months.

These can all be in different reports, but it would be great if they could be in one and a field identifying which date range they fall into.

I attempted to write a query using the query below:

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, ItemName
FROM OITM LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT ItemCode FROM RDR1 WHERE DocDate >= DATEADD(mm,-1,GetDate()) AND DocDate < DATEADD(mm,-3,GetDate()) GROUP BY ItemCode) RDR1 ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OnHand > 0 AND RDR1.ItemCode IS NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue sorry is that this query is returning all products and ignoring the date ranges.

Comment: What I would suggest is performing the queries separately but performing a UNION to return one resultset.Also use the BETWEEN x AND y syntax. It's much clearer that way, though not mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you.  You say that you don't want items ordered 3-6 months ago.  That seems utterly useless.  You probably want items not ordered in the last 12 months, in the last 9 months, in the lsat 6 months, and the last 3 months.

However, even that doesn't make sense.  Just put in the day -- or how long in the past -- it has been since an item was ordered.

To get this, use aggregation:

```
SELECT OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName,
       DATEDIFF(day, MAX(RDR1.DocDate), GETDATE()) as days_since_last_order
FROM OITM 
     RDR1
     ON OITM.ItemCode = RDR1.ItemCode
WHERE OITM .OnHand > 0 
GROUP BY OITM.ItemCode, OITM.ItemName;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon-Thank you for your response! Sorry I do not think that I was very clear in my initial question. What I am trying to do is create a slow moving stock report in Excel using a query with a data link to SAP B1. The date ranges are to give visibility to users on how slow they are and thats why I chose those ageing buckets. But I think you are right to pull the max doc date on the products but would that not ignore any previous transaction/postings which would effect the date? I tried to use your code but received an error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword "ON".

Comment: Any idea what could cause this? Thanks again

Comment: @Callum . . . Ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.